# How to test if a position of a php code is inside quotes?

Tags: php, syntax

I have some functions that operates php code (e.g.: removing comments from a final code). That functions use a function to test if some position is inside quotes and should be ignored:

```
function is_in_quotes($string, $pos){
    $Quote = array();
    $inis = 0;
    $inid = 0;
    $end = 0;
    while(strpos($string, "'", $inis)!==FALSE || strpos($string, '"', $inid)!==FALSE){
        $inis = (strpos($string, "'", $inis)===FALSE)? strlen($string) : strpos($string, "'", $inis) ;
        $inid = (strpos($string, '"', $inid)===FALSE)? strlen($string) : strpos($string, '"', $inid) ;
        if($inis<$inid){
            $ini = $inis;
            $end = (strpos($string, "'", $inis+1)===FALSE)? strlen($string) : strpos($string, "'", $inis+1) ;
        } else {
            $ini = $inid;
            $end = (strpos($string, "'", $inid+1)===FALSE)? strlen($string) : strpos($string, '"', $inid+1) ;
        }
        if($string{$ini-1}=="\\") { <== escape char test
            $inis = $ini+1;
            $inid = $ini+1;
        } else {
            $Quote[] = array($ini, $end);
            $inis = $end+1;
            $inid = $end+1;
        }
    }
    foreach($Quote as $Q){
        if($pos>$Q[0] && $pos<$Q[1]) return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

This routine finds opening quotation marks (single or double) and look for the closing position. Then it collects the ini - end to test later if $pos is inside one of those intervals.

I was heaving problems and did add the test for escape chars, so it will not consider the opening quotation mark. But there is another problem I just saw, so my question will split into two:

1) How to detect that an opening quotation mark should be ignored when inside a literal regular expression like this...

```
atTag[E[0]] = E[1].replace(/['"]+/g, '');
```

2) Is there another situation when an opening quote should be ignored, or this will be enough for the php syntax specifications?

Comment: [token_get_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php) might be helpful in your case. A [list of tokens](http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php) can be found here to help you find comments.